# what does ID3D11DeviceChild::SetPrivateDataInterface usage?

Tags: windows, directx, directx-11

the function in this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nn-d3d11-id3d11devicechild

this is useless code, dont see it, i just want to make this website happy

```
pContext->IAGetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &veBuffer, &Stride, &veBufferOffset);
if (veBuffer)
veBuffer->GetDesc(&vedesc);

D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bufferDesc;
bufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
bufferDesc.ByteWidth = vedesc.ByteWidth;
bufferDesc.BindFlags = 0;
bufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
bufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

ID3D11Device **pDeviceExtra = nullptr;
veBuffer->GetDevice(pDeviceExtra); //Can I use this to get to the device object?

//Create the buffer.
HRESULT hr = pDeviceExtra->CreateBuffer(&bufferDesc, NULL, &readVB);
assert(hr == S_OK);

pContext->CopyResource(readVB, veBuffer);
```

i know this function will set a iunknown interface to the device, but after that, how can i use this interface? what is this function mean?

i have try to search in web, but i cant find any anwser

Comment: Please do not put unrelated code and express the question clearly. Try to remove the useless code and fix the grammar.

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This API is not for general consumption. It's there for internal reasons, and in normal Direct3D programming you will never use `ID3D11DeviceChild::SetPrivateDataInterface`. In almost all cases it's going to do nothing and return `S_OK` or do nothing and return `E_NOTIMPL`.

The `ID3D11DeviceChild::SetPrivateData` method can be used to provide debug name information for the debug layer:

```
static const char c_szName[] = "My name";
hr = pContext->SetPrivateData( WKPDID_D3DDebugObjectName, sizeof( c_szName ) - 1, c_szName );
```

Otherwise, you don't really need to use the `ID3D11DeviceChild` interface itself for anything. Having an interface derived from it is mostly an indication that it's lifetime is tied to the lifetime of it's owning `ID3D11Device` instance regardless of that object's refcount: see [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/prog-dx-with-com).

Comment: `ID3D12PipelineLibrary::SetPrivateDataInterface` is useful for `CreatePipelineLibrary` to persist the lifetime of the data.